# python argparse: arg with no flag

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

i've the following code:

```
parser.add_argument('file', help='file to test')
parser.add_argument('-revs', help='range of versions', nargs='+', default=False)
```

Is there a way to not use the flag `-revs` when use it, like this:

```
./somescript.py settings.json 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 36):

Yes.

You have multiple solutions:

- As Mrav mentioned, you can use the system argument (sys.argv[0...])
- Or use argparse. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#example) (which is python3 compliant), you can do this way:

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      parser = ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument('file')
      parser.add_argument('revs', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+', help='revisions')
      res = parser.parse_args()
      pprint(res)
  ```

And you can see the result:

```
$ ./test.py  settings.json 1 2 3
Namespace(file='settings.json', revs=[1, 2, 3])
```